# amCharts LabelFunction not working

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/f3zy3bjc/

I'm trying to add a custom label to the end of each bar in a chart, like so:

```js
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "labelFunction": function(data) {return 'new label';}
  }],
```

The labelFunction property isn't working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Maybe:
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972032/amchart-change-label-color-of-axis)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a good question. The reason why it doesn't work is that `labelFunction` does not event get invoked if there are not label, and there are no label if `labelText` is not set.

So, as awkward as it may sound, you need to define `labelText` as well. You can set it to anything, it just need to produce a non-empty string.

```
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "labelText": " ",
    "labelFunction": function(data) {return 'new label';}
  }],
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3zy3bjc/1/).